# Spinner с выбором пола и отправлением на сервер

Tags: java, android

Надо создать spinner выбора пола. При выборе надписи "Мужской" на сервер отправляется "2", при выборе "Женский" - отправляется "1".
Мой spinner был создан путём описания содержимого в файле strings.xml
`<string-array name="gender_array">
       <item>Мужской</item>
       <item>Женский</item>
</string-array>`

На данный момент отправляет на сервер, либо "Мужской", либо "Женский".
Код:

```
spinGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGender);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_array, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinGender.setAdapter(adapter);
spinGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});

btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String genderId = spinGender.getSelectedItem().toString();


        utilStartService.startGetSignUpSecond(email, tel, surname, name, patronymic, genderId, year,  socialStatusId,stateId,  post, home, exemptionId, password, captcha, recieveEmail);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создайте спиннер.
2. Повесьте на него слушатель изменения значения
3. При изменении/нажатии к-л другой кнопки отправьте POST запрос на сервер
4. В пост запрос в качестве параметра передайте ваше число

В вашем случае вам надо в ресурсах поменять местами теги `item` и в слушателе отправлять на сервер `position+1`

Чтобы получить позицию выбранного элемента воспользуйтесь методом

```
spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Comment: Мне надо передавать просто 1, либо 2, место надписей "Мужской" и "женский".
Чтобы потом можно было составить статистику и этим единицам и двойкам.